# Python+requests: POST передача multipart/form-data в форму

Tags: python, requests

Всем привет, пытаюсь разобраться с post запросами и передачей данных в форму. Провожу опыты в postman'е и все вроде работает, но столкнулся с проблемой переноса кода в python.

В стандартной возможности экспорта кода в постмане это выглядит так:

```
import requests

url = "https://www.bpofulfillment.com/api/File/ClientRequestWithFile"

payload = "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"Context\"\r\n\r\nBpoComp\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"Action\"\r\n\r\nBpoAsset.BpoFileRequestPrc\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"Data[Action]\"\r\n\r\nUploadCompPdf\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"Data[AssetId]\"\r\n\r\n4530318\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"Data[Data][AssetId]\"\r\n\r\n4530318\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"Data[Data][OrderId]\"\r\n\r\n3135838\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"Data[Data][CompType]\"\r\n\r\nSale1\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"Data[Data][DocumentType]\"\r\n\r\nMLS\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"Data[Data][Upload]\"\r\n\r\ntrue\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"sold.pdf\"\r\nContent-Type: application/pdf\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--"

headers = {
'content-type': "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW",
'cookie': "ASP.NET_SessionId=dbyn3xdli5iugqtn1oulkyik;BPOFLogin=047FD1144C4400DD103E52BF4D13E31F42E6BFA1A94D78C7E53071B116418CBADC61597EE5F7369A21E22C1E33540691EC546FA950916342E530AE56BA80CEF0DB988ABC681C66A79F0A98EAF5009569EE0CC6FAD7E14E537652AE2E1BCD50C3DFDF9013DC7D6AA8E7F0358FA97526E9",
'cache-control': "no-cache",
'postman-token': "b0ceee14-63bd-423a-9e36-e6d3525b8142"
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)
```

Никак не соображу как это преобразовать в нормальный читабельный код с передачей файла. Перегуглил кучу запросов, но большая часть ответов идут более 5 лет назад, выглядят коротко и чудесным образом работают у всех кроме меня.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Официальная документация](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/) очень простая и очень информативная.

```
headers = {
    'cache-control': "no-cache",
}
cookies = {
    'ASP.NET_SessionId': 'dbyn3xdli5iugqtn1oulkyik',
    'BPOFLogin': '047FD1144C4400DD103E52BF4D13E31F42E6BFA1A94D78C7E53071B116418CBADC61597EE5F7369A21E22C1E33540691EC546FA950916342E530AE56BA80CEF0DB988ABC681C66A79F0A98EAF5009569EE0CC6FAD7E14E537652AE2E1BCD50C3DFDF9013DC7D6AA8E7F0358FA97526E9',
}
data = {
    'some_input_name': 'some input value',
    'another_input_name': 'another input value',
}
files = {
    'some_file_name': open('file.jpg', 'rb')
}

r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, cookies=cookies, data=data, files=files)
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.